# Are there working instances of Kilobot projects?

Tags: multi-agent

The interesting [Kilobot project](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/ssr/projects/progSA/kilobot.html) from Harvard for investigating multi-robot behavior with masses of small dumb robots has been made [open hardware](http://ssr.wikidot.com/kilobot-documents) for a year now.

However I cannot find so much activity about robot creation and movies about results. Is it too hard to create the robots, the programmer, the charger or isn't the project interesting enough?

Comment: Whoa, there are waay to many questions here. You may want to split it up. Aside from that, your questions (1),(4),(5) are of the "not constructive" type, they are rather make-a-list-y and likely to be closed. Your questions may be more suited to [chat]

Comment: I agree. This is a fishing or survey question. Please ask specific, answerable questions.

Comment: OK, I have updated, hopefully accordingly.

Comment: I believe swarm intelligence is not as hot a topic as it was before (was it the 80s?). That's probably why there isn't much effort in trying to implement something using kilobots.

Comment: Thanks rics, I think your update makes your question more practical.

Comment: Seconded.  Good update.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Nikolaus Correll at CU-Boulder is doing research with a derivative of the kilobots: http://www.colorado.edu/news/releases/2012/12/14/cu-boulder-team-develops-swarm-pingpong-ball-sized-robots

Comment: I would say that Correll's work is similar in spirit but it is not connected to Kilobots.